# JavaScript check if several numbers within a set are within a certain range

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have a list like this in JavaScript.

```js
var times1=[0,100,500,501,502,503,504]
var times2=[0,50,100,150,200,250,300]
```

And I need to check if any 5 numbers have a range of 10. For example, `times1` would be detected as `true` or positive as `500,501,502,503,504` are 5 numbers that are within a range of 10. `times2` however would be considered `false` or negative as all of its numbers are 50 apart.

For this could use a loop that goes through every number to see if it passes the condition, but is there any faster/better way to do this?

Comment: Javascript is really fast, especially when it comes to iterating arrays and working with numbers. My advice, don't be concerned with writing something "inefficient". Create something that works first, test it thoroughly, then see if there is room for optimizing it.

Comment: What expected result?

Comment: *"Basically, I have a list like this in JavaScript."* - Does "like this" mean pre-sorted? That aside, jwatts is right. Share what you've come up with so far and we can help you debug it, as opposed to just asking for code.

Comment: Additionally, there is no way to process a list of values without looping over them. Even if there was a `Array.prototype.hasFiveNumbersInRange(int range)` function, it would still have to loop over all the numbers one or more times to get the answer. :)

Comment: probably should show what you have tried that is "inefficient"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having a sorted array, you could get the fourth element before the actual element and check the delta.

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ends the iteration if the callback returns `true`.

```js
const check = array => array.some((a, i, { [i + 4]: b }) => b - a <= 10);

console.log(check([0, 100, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504]));
console.log(check([0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]));
```